# How do I paste long code samples and terminal output?

Tags: support

I want to insert a long console dump in my answer. It would be best if the text is scrollable. How do I get around the "feature" that lines in SE posts need to end in 2 spaces?

Comment: Have you tried formatting it as code or quote?

Comment: @Mysticial: If it doesn't work in plain text it probably won't work in a quote.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn SHHHH... Obviously I've never tried it with quotes... :P:P:P

Comment: Is there any chance the *entire* console dump isn't really necessary? Maybe you could just include relevant excerpts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Paste the text into your question/answer and select it with the mouse.

[image]

Then click the code button from the toolbar. All your text will be given code formatting and the line breaks preserved.

[image]

This will also make the text scrollable if you insert a really long dump.

[image]

Comment: Ehm, which website are you on?  My code button doesn't look like your code button.

Comment: @RobertHarvey that's AskUbuntu.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Looks like [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/). For some reason the code button looks like `<$>` there instead of `{}` like on SO.

Comment: Hmm. Sorry guys. I was using [ubuntu.se]. I'll update the screenshots. Also, the magic comment is `[ubuntu.se]` (confusing I know). (cc @RobertHarvey)

Comment: Even better, use the `<pre>` element so that you don't get weird syntax highlighting.

Comment: `<!-- language: lang-none -->` @RichardJ.RossIII.

Comment: @TRiG I am aware of that, but sometimes `pre` is easier,

Answer (score 2):

Please don't use regular HTML `<pre>` tags to format code. Use the code formatting. That will make long messages scrollable. If you're worried about weird syntax highlighting being applied incorrectly, you can disable syntax highlighting by inserting `<!-- language: lang-none -->` on a line by itself before the code block.

Comment: `<Pre>` blocks are scrollable just like code blocks.

Comment: Are they, @RobKennedy? I hadn't noticed that. Right.

Answer (score 1):

If you're pasting long code, then select it all and format it as code, as demonstrated in [Seth's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/176801/33732). The keyboard shortcut for that is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>.

If what you're pasting isn't code (such as compiler output, log messages, or a custom data format), then [use regular HTML to format it](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#html) instead of running it through the code highlighter. Put `<pre>` at the start of your text and `</pre>` at the end. There's no need to indent text formatted that way.

Comment: +1 for the keyboard shortcut, though personally, I like using the formatting for anything code-ish, whether it's terminal output or something like JS. It's just easier on the eyes (IMO anyway).